# JSON reponse for Jquery/Ajax in Wordpress fails for bigger size file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am implementing own custom function for historical extract in CSV format from MySQL database using jQuery-Ajax in WordPress environment. I have an HTML where user selects the start date and end date and clicks on a button and then the process works.

When the JSON response is in the range of 900kb to 1 MB, then extraction works. But when the response size increases beyond this then AJAX callback goes in error and returns nothing.

Below is the JavaScript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    jQuery('#extract_btn').click(function(){

        var startdate = jQuery( '#from-date' ).val();        
        var enddate = jQuery( '#to-date' ).val();

        var data1 = {
            action: 'hist_extract',
            fromdate: startdate,
            todate: enddate
        };

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php

        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:MyAjax1.ajaxurl, 
            data:data1,
            success:function(response) {
                if (response == '')
                    return;
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + JSON.parse(response));
                JSONToCSVConvertor(response, "Historic Price", true);
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
                alert('Error in response'); 
                var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });
    });
});

function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    alert('Start of Json Convertor')
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';
    //Set Report title in first row or line

    //CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";

        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {

            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }

        row = row.slice(0, -1);

        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";

        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }

        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }

    alert(CSV);

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "Edding_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");

    //this trick will generate a temp "a" tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.id="lnkDwnldLnk";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    var blob = new Blob([CSV]);

    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)  // IE hack; 
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName+".csv");
    else
    {
        var a = window.document.createElement("a");
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, {type: "text/plain"});
        a.download = fileName+".csv";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();  // IE: "Access is denied"    
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
}
```

Below is the functions.php having custom hook:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Below is the custom Javascript hook for Historic Extract
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function price_history() {
    $handle = 'hist_extract';
    $list = 'enqueued';

    if (wp_script_is( $handle, $list )) {
        return;
    }
    else
    {  
        // registering and enqueueing the Javascript/Jquery
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('hist_extract', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Historic_Price.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
        wp_enqueue_script('hist_extract');
        wp_localize_script('hist_extract', 'MyAjax1', array(
            // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
            // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
            'security' => wp_create_nonce('my-special-string')
        ));

        error_log('Js for Historic Price loaded successfully');
        error_log(admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'price_history');

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Custom function that handles the AJAX hook for Historic Extract
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function historic_data_extract() {
    error_log('Start of report data function on ajax callback');
    // check_ajax_referer( 'my-special-string', 'security' );
    $from_date = $_POST['fromdate'];
    $to_date = $_POST['todate'];
    $convert_from_date= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from_date));
    $convert_to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($to_date));
    error_log($from_date );
    error_log($to_date);
    error_log($convert_from_date);
    error_log($convert_to_date);
    //******************************************
    //Custom Code for fetching data from server database
    //********************************************

    //header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    define("dbhost", "localhost");
    define("dbuser", "xxxxxxxxx");
    define("dbpass", "xxxxxxxxx");
    define("db", "xxxxxxxx");

    $emparray = array();
    $conn = mysqli_connect(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, db);
    // Change character set to utf8
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

    if ($conn )
    {
        $query = "SELECT PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_PRODUCT_ID,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_URL_ID,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_SHOP_NAME,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_LAST_CHECKED,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_CUST_PROD_CODE,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_PRODUCT_NAME,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_LAST_PRICE,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_CONV_PRICE,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_DOMAIN,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_COUNTRY_CODE,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_AVAILABLE,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_AVAIL_DESCR,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_PRICE_TIME,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_FAULT_FLAG,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_FAULT_TIME,PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_FAULT_MSG,TABLE_72.MIN_PRICE,TABLE_72.MAX_PRICE,TABLE_72.AVG_PRICE,TABLE_72.DEV_PRICE
                  FROM PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL
                  INNER JOIN TABLE_72 ON   PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_URL_ID=TABLE_72.PR_URL_ID AND
                  PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_SHOP_NAME=TABLE_72.PR_SHOP_NAME   AND
                  PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_PRODUCT_NAME=TABLE_72.PR_PRODUCT_NAME
                  AND PR_PRICE_HIST_TBL.PR_LAST_CHECKED BETWEEN '$convert_from_date' AND '$convert_to_date';";
        error_log($query);
        $result_select= mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        error_log(mysqli_num_rows($result_select));
        error_log(mysqli_error($conn));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select))
        {   
            error_log(json_encode($row)); 
            $emparray[] = $row;

        }

        //error_log(json_encode($emparray));

        echo json_encode($emparray);
        die();
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_hist_extract', 'historic_data_extract');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hist_extract', 'historic_data_extract');
```

From the code above, you can see, I have tried to implement many things by going over different forums. But I am stuck here. I am not able to understand where could be the potential problem. FYI..I am hosting this on GoDaddy Server. I tried below things:

1. Tried to make query execution faster by removing views from join. It seems, query is fetching results in around 15 seconds
2. Format of the data in JSON and tried async: false, but not working
3. Tried to modify values in init.php. But of no use.

   pload_max_filesize = 64M
   post_max_size = 64M
   memory_limit = 400M
   file_uploads = On
   max_execution_time = 300
4. Tried to implement (error:function) for AJAX response. Where only the first alert('Error in response'); is throwing. But can not see the XHR response text.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if I miss something or want more information.

Comment: Can you print $emparray array for large data, Is that data fetching perfectly, You can see in browser XHR.

Comment: Yes...I can print the resulting array in json_encode in error_log. Just that because of shear size of data, error_log swells to MBs and takes a lot of time to open.

Comment: Just give a try by increasing limit of `LimitRequestBody `

Comment: I updated the 'LimitRequestBody 4000000' in .htaccess file in my server root directory. But still not working. Is that the correct location I am updating ?

Comment: If you have created Virtual host, Update there too

Comment: I don't think so I understand you Sudarshan correctly here...I am using cpanel/fileexplorer for my server updates. And I guess I don't have any virtual host.

Comment: You may have to look your PHP errors log

Comment: `LimitRequestBody` is obviously nonsense to begin with, when there’s problem with the _response_ size - clue kinda in the name here.

Comment: _“But when the response size increases beyond this then AJAX callback goes in error and returns nothing”_ - so that this is based on “response size” is rather a guess by now? What does the response to the request look like, when you inspect it via browser dev tools? I hope you have proper PHP error reporting enabled to begin with?

Comment: repsonse is a json array. I use error_log function to log it. Just that when, array size increases then it takes whole lot of time open the error log which is normal I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve the issue is to have a good night's sleep.
Thanks for your clues.

Issue was: In xhr my ajax request was going in cancelled status.

Solution: I was missing preventdefault() in my function.

Now I can see MBs of JSON response. Thanks again for provided clues.
Currently preventdefault() has solved my issue. If you feel, anything else also needs to be taken care as a best practice in my code. Please do not hesitate to comment.

Thanks.